How to pnpm install package from deno jsr?
I have pnpm-managed monorepo workspace. I want to install package which was published on deno repo using jsr.
How would I do that?
NOTE: previously I've been using npm and jsr has workaround for that which worked fine. But now I'm migrating to workspace/monorepo and switched to pnpm workspaces.

jsr is just another registry. You can even see the pnpm logo on their homepage. You put it to .npmrc and it will work with pnpm the same way it worked with npm CLI.

To add a JSR package to a project managed by pnpm, you can use the following command:
pnpm dlx jsr add @{jsr_author_name}/{jsr_package_name}
Replace {deno_author_name} and {deno_package_name} with the actual package information.
As noted on the JSR website:

JSR isn't a replacement for the npm registry; it's a superset of npm.

Running the jsr command will add the dependency to your package.json file, along with a .npmrc file to your project root with the necessary config to use JSR with npm.

The question asked how to use the command pnpm install. This does not currently answer the question.

This specific command does not work.
@kotkifotki
What worked for me:
First, add deno repository to the .npmrc manually.
Then use pnpm CLI as normal.

@DmitryKaigorodov I've verified the command works on my side (Deno 2.1.3). Note that JSR configures the .npmrc file at the project root.
